# Call Android like JavascriptInterface in flutter webview

Tags: javascript, android, flutter

```
 public class WebAppInterface {
    Context context;

    public WebAppInterface(Context c) {
      context = c;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public String getLogInToken() {
      return "test";
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public String getAgent() {
      return "data";
    }
}
```

I want to create above interface in flutter webview. can someone help this how can i call in flutter webview.

I have tried addJavaScriptHandler and evaluateJavascript method